# Html Table Row Alignment

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I am trying to show/hide rows on the basis of "Domain Type" selected(third combobox in the first row) ,which breaks the alignment. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

How can I effectively show/hide rows and persist the alignment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** EDIT **

To "hide" elements, use the "**visibility**" property instead of "**display**" property

For tables, use

```
style.visibility="collapse" and style.visibility="visible"
```

For all other elements, use

```
style.visibility="hidden" and style.visibility="visible"
```

Comment: Hi jao, it seems to be working , but after hiding 2nd row (selecting per file type ) there is a gap for 2nd row . How can I place the third row in place of 2nd row ?

Comment: It looks like @Usman: got it :) just change "hidden" to "collapse"

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
   <script>
      function getTypes()
      {
          if(document.getElementById("displayType").value.indexOf("rlo")!=-1)
             {
                 document.getElementById("secondRow").style.visibility="visible";
                 document.getElementById("thirdRow").style.visibility="collapse";

              }
          else
              {
                  if(document.getElementById("displayType").value.indexOf("ft")!=-1)
                     {
                      document.getElementById("secondRow").style.visibility="collapse";
                      document.getElementById("thirdRow").style.visibility="visible";
                      }
               }
           }
</script>
```